# How can i send a hidden value to action class using Struts2

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I need to send a value to action class when a click on a link. This is my code:

```
<s:iterator value="results" var = "item">   
   <li><pre>
       <a href="<s:url action="getCompanies"/>" class="selectable"><b></b><s:property value="%{#item.getGroupName()}"/> (<span class="count"><s:property value="%{#item.getNrCompanies()}"/></span>)<s:hidden value="%#item.getGroupId()}" name="GroupId" id="GroupId" /></a>
   </pre></li>
</s:iterator>
```

I need to be sent back  **%#item.getGroupId()}** depending on the option I choose from iterator.

```
<s:hidden value="%#item.getGroupId()}" name="GroupId" id="GroupId" />
```

I have the getter and setter for Group Id but it's does't reach action class.

Thank you

Comment: `value="%#item.getGroupId()}`opening `{` brace is missing in your code, is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok if the group id appears in the user's browser's address bar?  if so, then you can add params to a url like this:

```
<s:iterator value="results" var = "item">   

   <s:url var="companyUrl" action="getCompanies">
      <s:param name="groupId" value="%{#item.getGroupId()}"/>
   </s:url>

   <li>
      <pre>
         <a href="${ companyUrl }" class="selectable">
            <b><s:property value="%{#item.getGroupName()}"/></b>
            (<span class="count"><s:property value="%{#item.getNrCompanies()}"/></span>)
         </a>
      </pre>
   </li>

</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem you have may be due to `name="GroupId"`. Change it to `name="groupId"`.
Also change `value="%#item.getGroupId()}` to `value="%{#item.getGroupId()}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:hidden value="%#item.getGroupId()}" name="GroupId" id="GroupId" />
```

try the below one it seems you had not open `{` braces

```
<s:hidden name="groupId" value="%{#item.getGroupId}"></s:hidden>
```